# Query a $resource in AngularJS with params

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I have a api that displays a list of transactions between 2 dates.
I would like to access that data as an angular resource.
When I try what happens is I get a bunch of

```
GET /trans/12-01-2014/12-02-2014 200 1690ms - 953.2kb
GET /trans 404 1ms
GET /trans 404 1ms
DELETE /trans 404 3ms
POST /trans 404 3ms
DELETE /trans 404 0ms
```

Followed by more of the same.

It still returns the data with extra methods providing by resource.
I don't want to query /trans route on its own because that is invalid and the dates are required.

```
var myApp = angular.module('appServices', ['ngResource','ngRoute']);

myApp.factory('Trans', ['$resource',
  function($resource){

return $resource('/trans/:start/:end',{},{
    query: {method:'GET', isArray:true}
});

  }]);
```

Then a little code from the controller.js

```
function($scope,$routeParams,$http,Trans){
$scope.trans = [];

$scope.trans =Trans.query({start: $routeParams.start, end:
 $routeParams.end});
```

Any help would be appreciated, I'm new to angularjs and node.

Comment: Also I've thought I don't need everything that comes along with using $resource and attempted an $http call to my api in controller, but when I do this I retrieve no data or the page doesn't update

Comment: Plunker would be cool. And code on that `$http` stuff.

Comment: @MikkoViitala I went and looked over what I was trying to do with $http and now it's working how I want it to. However could you direct me toward any resources on using $resource other than the api? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I can just point you to Google or here http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bangularjs%5D+%24resource :)

Comment: "When I try what happens is I get a bunch of"  ? If you clean up your post I can help.  I dont understand your issue.  It looks like the query worked, but the server is returning a 404 for the others.  You are probably going to have to define a custom $resource to handle the query so the "get/delete/save" can post to resource/:id

Comment: @Nix Correct, the query worked, but I'm getting 404s on things I'm not trying to look for. Also the query is returning 6 extra data fields object object which seem to be methods provided by $resource. So maybe a clearer set of questions are. 1) "What do I do with these extra fields or how do I avoid getting them returned with raw data? 2) How do I write a custom resource (basically would like a clear example) 3) Why am I getting 404s based off the factory method and controller I have above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/zdfbz7tx/) that hopefully helps you out.  You need to update `id` with whatever your rest structure looks like.

```
mod.factory('MyResource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://unboxedtechnology.com/trans/:id/:start/:end',{},{
                query: {method:'GET', isArray:true}
   });
});
```

This would support

```
MyResource.query({start: ... ,end: ...}})
//GET /trans/:start/:end

resourceInstance.$get({id: ... , }})
// GET /trans/:id

resourceInstance.$create({ ... }})
// POST /trans/

resourceInstance.$update({id: ... , }})
// PUT /trans/:id

resourceInstance.$delete({id: ... , }})
// DELETE /trans/id
```